# Changing the Value of a Span tag using JavaScript via Name

Tags: javascript

I'm working on making a timer application, but at the moment, I have the timers set to their default values, 5:00, until the image above is clicked. The code for clicking the image is this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="Timer1()"><img src="images/Icons/image.png" id="id"></a>
```

When that is clicked, I want it to adjust the following span code:

```
<span id="timer" class="one" name="blue1">5:00</span>
```

However, there are many parts to the code and with my CSS styles, I can't really spare the ID or class variables, so I'd like to use JavaScript to target this timer by its one unshared name, which is the name="blue1". Here is my JavaScript for now.

```
function BlueTimer1() {

document.getElementsByName('blue1').innerHTML="blah";

}
```

Obviously it will actually *do* something once I am done with it, but for now I just need to be able to modify the text within the span, I don't care what it edits it to.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements with the same ID? That's just wrong. But as you'd learn in a basic tutorial, `getElementsByName` returns an Array-like collection, so you'd need to access members of the collection.

Comment: I would guess the answer provided by werewolf is correct. And you might also consider to change the `onClick` to `onclick` to avoid warning prompt from eclipse. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `document.getElementsByName('blue1')` will return a collection/array like object of spans even there is only one so you need to select the first one using:

```
document.getElementsByName('blue1')[0].innerHTML="blah";
```

So it'll work, but if you use `getElementById('timer')` then you can do it usong:

```
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML="blah";
```

Make sure you have only one element using one `id`, which means an `id` must be unique.